# Removing extra information in pandas.Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I am trying to do a sum on a pandas dataframe column that I've gotten from a SQL database.

The output that I'm getting is:

0    385020.85

dtype: float64

How do I remove the index number and the dtype from the output?

Here is my code:

```
        date = self.md.get()
        month = date[0:2]
        year = date[2:7]

        db = pymysql.connect("localhost", "user", "password", "database")
        cursor = db.cursor()

        query = f"SELECT `Column5` FROM `table` WHERE `Code` = 'XX' AND `Some_Value` != 0 AND LEFT(`Date`, 2) = '{month}' AND RIGHT(`Date`, 4) = '{year}'"
        cursor.execute(query)
        results = cursor.fetchall()

        df = pd.DataFrame(results)

        month_total = df.sum()
        print(month_total)
```

Comment: Add a `.item()` at the end, since it is a single value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is you're using sum on the entire dataframe, so it expects to have to return/print multiple different sums.

The fix to isolate the value you want to print and clean the output would look something like...

```
month_total = df['Column5'].sum()
```

...or...

```
print(df.sum()[0])
```